# How can I best do accurate cross-browser testing on pages?

Tags: responsive-design, web

My goal is to get together a really solid set of testing environments for my web development. I want to leverage more HTML5/CSS3 and need to develop my toolchain better for testing in different browser environments.

I natively work in Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows.  I have a mac laptop but can't always have it with me when travelling.

This is how I envision getting all environments on one laptop:
1. Ubuntu Linux (xubuntu/xfce)
2. Virtualbox / Windows
3. Virtualbox / Hackintosh
4. IOS dev environment (virtualbox ?)
5. Android Dev environment (native linux?)

Anyone have input?

This is all spurred by recently viewing one of my sites on an original iPad which still has IOS5 / Safari5. i realized that not just windows technology is crufty anymore. Internet Explorer and Safari are starting to run into many of the same long term web compatibility issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try something like https://www.equafy.com?
there is a free plan that shall include all but Mac.

Comment: NOTE: The author of this post is affiliated with the website linked in this answer.